# capturing a certain member of an INET node, SNR specifically in omnetpp

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I have defined a network topology in omnet++ along with host parameters.
here is the NED code:

```
network Basic
{
    parameters:
        string hostType = default("AODVRouter");
        string mediumType = default("APSKScalarRadioMedium");

    submodules:
        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            @display("p=919.664,62.247997");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=755.008,62.247997");
        }
        radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            @display("p=558.224,62.247997");
        }
        hostA: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=104.416,427.70398");
        }
        hostB: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=664.648,267.064");
        }

}
```

I want to create a module which records the SNR/SINR of each station every time it sends/receives a message.

After a few hours of searching (both googling and manual searching in the INET library implementations).

I did not find how to access it so far from another module (I do not know where the field is actually present not how to access it from another module).

Thanks in advance.